# How to change date format when inherit in odoo (python)?

Tags: python, odoo

First, i have one model inherit to model purschase.order. I want change datetime from purchase.order to date format in my inherit model

> this field from purchase.order :

```
date_order = fields.Datetime('Order Deadline', required=True, states=READONLY_STATES, index=True, copy=False, default=fields.Datetime.now,\
    help="Depicts the date where the Quotation should be validated and converted into a purchase order.")
```

please help me, thank you for your time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ERD You can use [widget='date'](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/hr_recruitment/views/hr_recruitment_views.xml#L39) in XML

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add this field

```
date_order = fields.Date(required=True, default=fields.Date.today,\
    help="Depicts the date where the Quotation should be validated and converted into a purchase order.")
```

to your inherited model and then replace date_order in the tree and form view with this one